# Python - Testar permissões de leitura

Tags: python, python-2.7

Existe alguma função que retorne, em Python, `True` caso eu tenha permissões de leitura do ficheiro em python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`access(path, mode)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access) do módulo [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os).

Veja um exemplo:

```
if os.access("foo.txt", os.R_OK):
    with open("foo.txt") as fp:
        # Fazer algo aqui
```

O primeiro parâmetro da função é o caminho do arquivo a ser verificado e o segundo parâmetro é usado para especificar o modo a ser utilizado.

Os modos são:

- `os.F_OK`: Para testar a existência de *path*.
- `os.R_OK`: Usado para verificar se *path* pode ser lido.
- `os.W_OK`: Para verificar a capacidade de escrita  de *path*.
- `os.X_OK`: Para verificar se *path* pode ser executado.

Como alternativa pode-se usar a função [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) também pertencente ao módulo `os` em conjunto com o módulo auxiliar [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#module-stat) que permite trabalhar com um conjunto maior de opções.

```
import os
import stat

filename = "foo.txt"
if os.path.exists(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    print (bool(st.st_mode & stat.S_IRUSR))
else:
    print ("{0} nao foi encontrado.".format(filename))
```

Usamos uma operação [bitwise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) `&` para avaliar se cada *bit* de saída é *1* se o *bit* correspondente do atributo `ST_MODE` e `S_IRUSR` é *1*, se não é *0* e usamos o resultado da operação na função [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) que ira mostrar *True* ou *False*.

- [`ST_MODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.ST_MODE): É usado para obter os *bits* de proteção do arquivo.
- [`S_IRUSR`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_IRUSR): Proprietário tem permissão de leitura.

Comment: A parte "with open("foo.txt") as fp:" é mesmo necessária ?

Comment: @HelpNeeded101 Não necessariamente utilizei apenas como exemplo.